# Image links are incorrect when an image is inserted before another image

Tags: bug, images, uploader

Image links are incorrect when an image is inserted before another image. Example:

[image]

The output:

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[![enter image description here][2]][1]
```

should have been

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
```

Comment: The issue is still present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug appears to have been fixed.